# How to get only full hour data

Tags: javascript, sql, sql++

Hy in my DB i have data that occurs every 10 min (timestamp) and i would like to get only those that have timestamp that is equal to full hours  between one timeframe

for example only those that have timestamp time equal 09.00, 10.00, 11.00, 12.00, 13.00

Comment: `WHERE timestamp = ? OR timestamp = ? ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract the minute portion of the timestamp with `DATE_PART_STR(mydate, 'minute')` then compare it to zero.

Comment: CRATE INDEX ix1 ON mybucket(DATE_PART_STR(mydate, 'minute')); SELECT d.* FROM mybucket AS d WHERE DATE_PART_STR(mydate, 'minute') = 0;